# VSCode extension that packages .d.ts file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've created a new `.d.ts` file which will enable autocomplete whenever a particular global object is used in the code.

How do I package this `.d.ts` file as part of an extension, so that, anyone can install this extension and use the autocomplete/intellisense ?

Comment: Declaration files should be published elsewhere, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html They are not in scope of a VSCode extension.

Comment: I have seen extensions that come with typings files. So, it's not unusual.